# Azure Storage Firewall, how to add/delete allowed public IPs by Rest API or SDK

Tags: azure-storage, azure-api-management, azure-storage-files, azure-fluent-api

I need to programmatically insert/remove Firewall IP entries, from a .NET desktop app, to an Azure storage account to temporary allow SMB access through the internet when my customers are out of office. I've found a solutions to retrieve the list of the allowed public IPs/IP ranges already set but not to insert/delete IPs by REST Api or .NET Sdk. Does anybody have a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/create#networkruleset) is the rest api call you are interested in. By the same token create\edit storage account SDK call would have these properties

Comment: BTW, you can also use PATCH API which supports partial update: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/update#networkruleset

Comment: I've found every answer here https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net